# how to write the for loops for this array (make/model/year/engine size)

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
$mmy = array(array("Chevrolet Truck", "C 1500 SERIES", "2005", "V8 5.7L (K)"),
    array("Nissan Pickup", "D21 PICKUP", "1993", "2.4 L"),
    array("TOYOTA CAMRY", "LE", "2001", "2.8L V6")
);

var_dump($mmy);


echo "<pre>";

echo "<h1>Data in 2-dimensional array Make/Model/Year/Engine</h1>";

echo "<ul>";
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    echo "<li><b>The row number $row</b>";
    echo "<ul>";

    for ($make = 0; $make < 4; $make++) {
        echo "<li>" . $mmy[$row][$make] . "</li>";
    }
    for ($model = 1; $model < 4; $model++) {
        echo "<li>" . $mmy[$row][$make][$model] . "</li>";
    }
    for ($year = 2; $year < 4; $year++) {
        echo "<li>" . $mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year] . "</li>";
    }
    for ($eng = 3; $eng < 4; $eng++) {
        echo "<li>" . $mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year][$eng] . "</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

without suppressing error reporting I get:
http://dpaste.org/iy0rD/#L9

I'm unclear where the offsets errors are coming from. I'm not used to programming in PHP. I have to write a PHP application that imports a CSV file and displays the results. This is just part of the overall program. For now I've statically defined the array for testing purposes. Hopefully this question is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, the way you're iterating over the $mmy array isn't correct.  By defining it like this:

```
$mmy = array(array("Chevrolet Truck", "C 1500 SERIES", "2005", "V8 5.7L (K)"),
    array("Nissan Pickup", "D21 PICKUP", "1993", "2.4 L"),
    array("TOYOTA CAMRY", "LE", "2001", "2.8L V6")
);
```

You're creating an array that contains 3 entries: each an array that contain 4 entries.  These are stored at the keys 0-3.  So, to iterate over your array like you have it, do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mmy); $i++) {
    $row = $mmy[$i];

    echo "<li><b>The row number $i</b>";
    echo "<ul>";

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($row); $j++) {
       echo "<li>" . $row[$j] . "</li>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

This will iterate through the outer row, generating a ul tag, then inside of it will generate an li tag for each element in the inner array.

You only need one inner loop here.  The outer loop will iterate over all of top level entries in $mmy, and the inner loop will iterate over what is inside the inner arrays.

A possibly superior solution is to use arrays with user defined keys, like so:

```
$mmy = array(
    array('make' => "Chevrolet Truck", 'model' => "C 1500 SERIES", 'year' => "2005", 'engine' => "V8 5.7L (K)"),
    array('make' => "Nissan Pickup", 'model' => "D21 PICKUP", 'year' => "1993", 'engine' => "2.4 L"),
    array('make' => "TOYOTA CAMRY", 'model' => "LE", 'year' => "2001", 'engine' => "2.8L V6")
);
```

By defining your array like that, you can easily access the values at each key like this:

```
$mmy[0]['make'];    // This returns Chevrolet Truck, for the first (0th) element of the array, and the 'make' key
```

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that offset [4] in the array does not exist. Use `isset()` to determine if an item (key) in an array exists or not.

```
for ($eng = 3; $eng < 3; $eng++) {
   if (isset($mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year][$eng])) {
      echo '<li>', $mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year][$eng], '</li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Use isset($eng) for example?

Comment: Use `isset($mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year][$eng])`

Comment: @silkfire You do realize that his array is 2 dimensional right?

Comment: @ITroubs Obviously not if he's using 5 brackets :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone! Learned quite a bit about PHP and 2 dimensional arrays/etc.

Comment: @silkfire OBVIOUSLY HE doesn't know what he is doing! looking at his source code it is clear that it is 2 dimensional

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$mmy = array(  array("Chevrolet Truck", "C 1500 SERIES", "2005","V8 5.7L (K)"),
                array("Nissan Pickup", "D21 PICKUP", "1993", "2.4 L"),
                array("TOYOTA CAMRY", "LE", "2001","2.8L V6")
            );

var_dump($mmy);


echo "<pre>";

echo "<h1>Data in 2-dimensional array Make/Model/Year/Engine</h1>";

echo "<ul>";
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    echo "<li><b>The row number $row</b>";
    echo "<ul>";

for ($make = 0; $make < 4; $make++) {
    echo "<li>".$mmy[$row][$make]."</li>";
}
for ($model = 3; $model < 3; $model++) {
    echo "<li>".$mmy[$row][$make][$model]."</li>";
}
for ($year = 3; $year < 3; $year++) {
    echo "<li>".$mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year]."</li>";
}
for ($eng = 3; $eng < 3; $eng++) {
    echo "<li>".$mmy[$row][$make][$model][$year][$eng]."</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two basic loops that you can use:

```
foreach($theArray as $row){
    foreach($row as $column){
        echo $column;
    }
}

for($row=0;$row < count($array);$row++){
    for($column=0;$column < count($array[$row]);$column++){
        echo $array[$row][$column];
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the index numbers then use the foreach approach.
If you do want to use the index numbers then use the for loop.

in your example you have a 2 dimensional array looking like that:

```
Make            | Model         | Year | Engine
Chevrolet Truck | C 1500 SERIES | 2005 | V8 5.7L (K)
Nissan Pickup   | D21 PICKUP    | 1993 | 2.4 L
TOYOTA CAMRY    | LE            | 2001 | 2.8L V6
```

To access tem statically you do it like this:

```
$firstMake = $mmy[0][0]; //meaning first row first column
$secondMake = $mmy[1][0];
$thirdYear = $mmy[2][2];
```

I hope that clears it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array iterator:

```
<?php

$data = array(
  array("Chevrolet Truck", "C 1500 SERIES", "2005", "V8 5.7L (K)"),
  array("Nissan Pickup", "D21 PICKUP", "1993", "2.4 L"),
  array("TOYOTA CAMRY", "LE", "2001", "2.8L V6")
);

$data = new ArrayObject($data);
$iterator = $data->getIterator();

while ($iterator->valid())
{
  $value = $iterator->current();
  echo "<ul><li>The row number is: {$iterator->key()}</li>";
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($value); $x++) {
    echo "<li>{$value[$x]}</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
  $iterator->next();
}

?>
```

Note the use of `count` for the inner loop, this ensures that the loop will only echo out values that are defined within the array (so no undefined index errors should one value be missing).

Answer (score 0):

The errors are coming from the `echo`s. PHP is reporting that the object that you have asked for (for example `$mmy[$row][$make]`) does not exist.

After the end of the loop:

```
for ($make = 0; $make < 4; $make++) {
    echo "<li>" . $mmy[$row][$make] . "</li>";
}
```

`$make = 4`, so the first time through the next loop, PHP is trying to access `$mmy[0][4][1]` which does not exist. The same error exists with the following loops.

You can either put the loops inside each other, thereby never getting to the point where an *index* is greater than the length of the array, but you will still need to alter the array access since you are attempting to use a multi-dimensional lookup but your array is only 2-dimensional. Alternatively, use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as a different approach to outputting the data.

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "<h1>Data in 2-dimensional array Make/Model/Year/Engine</h1>";

echo "<ul>";
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    echo "<li><b>The row number $row</b>";
    echo "<ul><li>";

    echo implode("</li><li>", $mmy[$row]);

    echo "</li></ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</pre>";
```